# sniff ssthresh using libpcap

Tags: libpcap

Can we sniff SSTHRESH  value for a active connection using libpcap. I have included netinet/tcp.h in my program, but it gives junk values.  Is there any function or any other kernel file that i have to include in my sniff program. Can you please show the function which gets ssthresh value.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we sniff SSTHRESH value for a active connection using libpcap.

No.  The slow-start threshold is an internal parameter of the TCP implementation - there isn't even a guarantee that the TCP implementations on the two sides of a connection even support slow-start (although most if not all do, these days).  It is not a parameter that is transmitted in the TCP header of a TCP segment.

It might be possible to *infer* its value by looking at the behavior of TCP in a sufficiently large capture, but even that might not be possible with all captures.